# How do I ensure complete unit test coverage?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, reflection, tdd

I have 2 projects, one is the "Main" project and the other is the "Test" project.

The policy is that all methods in the Main project must have at least one accompanying test in the test project.

What I want is a new unit test in the Test project that verifies this remains the case.  If there are any methods that do not have corresponding tests (and this includes method overloads) then I want this test to fail.

I can sort out appropriate messaging when the test fails.

My guess is that I can get every method (using reflection??) but I'm not sure how to then verify that there is a reference to each method in this Test project (and ignore references in projects)

Comment: This is crazy. Read about test-driven development instead.

Comment: You can enable Code Coverage to automatically do all of this for you. You do not need to write anything specific, just set in the configuration which projects to include in the Code Coverage results. It will be calculated when you run the Unit Tests.

Comment: this sounds like a way to ensure very big methods in the "Main" project :) I would suggest read about *behavior* dirven development.

Comment: That is kind of a bad requirement. Just because you have a test that touches a method doesn't mean it hits all the code paths through the method. Code coverage is what you're looking for. After you run all the tests in a project, Code Coverage will tell you which code paths were not hit, enabling you to add new tests to cover those paths.

Comment: http://blog.zuehlke.com/en/tests-gone-bad-2/

Comment: Check out http://www.ncrunch.net/   That can quickly tell you (visually, using coloured symbols in the Visual Studio IDE) which methods do, or do not, have unit tests covering them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any existing software to measure code coverage but...

Don't do it!!! Seriously.  The aim should be not to have 100% coverage but to have software that can easily evolve.  From your test project you can invoke by reflection every single existing method and swallow all the exceptions.  That will make your coverage around 100% but what good would it be?

Read about TDD.  Start creating testable software that has meaningful tests that will save you when something goes wrong.  It's not about coverage, it's about being safe.

Comment: For instance, if you are developing a service, create a service as mostly an empty shell that loads a related library containing your functionality. You should not need to test the service itself, only the library which contains the functionality. Also ensure that your library is structured in such a way as to provide small testable pieces that are specific for their use, but as re-usable as possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a meta-test that sounds good in principle, but once you get to the detail you should quickly realise is a bad idea.  As has already been suggested, the correct approach is to encourage whoever owns the policy to amend it.  As you’ve quoted the policy, it is sufficiently specific that people can satisfy the requirement without really achieving anything of value.

Consider:

```
public void TestMethod1Exists()
{
    try
    {
        var classUnderTest = new ClassToTest();
        classUnderTest.Method1();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

The test contains a call to `Method1` on the `ClassToTest` so the requirement of having a test for that method is satisfied, but nothing useful is being tested.  As long as the method exists (which is must if the code compiled) the test will pass.

The intent of the policy is presumably to try to ensure that written code is being tested.  Looking at some very basic code:

```
public string IsSet(bool flag)
{
    if (flag)
    {
        return "YES";
    }
    return "NO";
}
```

As methods go, this is pretty simple (it could easily be changed to one line), but even so it contains two routes through the method.  Having a test to ensure that this method is being called gives you a false sense of security.  You would know it is being called but you would not know if all of the code paths are being tested.

An alternative that has been suggested is that you could just use code coverage tools.  These can be useful and give a much better idea as to how well exercised your code is, but again they only give an indication of the coverage, not the quality of that coverage.  So, let’s say I had some tests for the `IsSet` method above:

```
public void TestWhenTrue()
{
    var classUnderTest = new ClassToTest();
    Assert.IsString(classUnderTest.IsSet(true));
}
public void TestWhenFalse()
{
    var classUnderTest = new ClassToTest();
    Assert.IsString(classUnderTest.IsSet(false));
}
```

I’m passing sufficient parameters to exercise both code paths, so the coverage for the `IsSet` method should be 100%.  But all I am testing is that the method returns a string.  I’m not testing the value of the string, so the tests themselves don’t really add much (if any) value.

Code coverage is a useful metric, but only as part of a larger picture of code quality.  Having peer reviews and sharing best practice around how to effectively test the code you are writing within your team, whilst it is less concretely measurable will have a more significant impact on the quality of your test code.